# Create binary string in Javascript and convert in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, filereader

I have a file upload area in my JavaScript application. When i upload the file i use JS FileReader to get a binary string of the uploaded file. I then pass this to my C# WebApi and attempt to Write this to a file so that i can be stored on the server.

JS Code

```
let myFile = ev.target.files[0];
if(myFile.size > 0){
    let reader = new FileReader();
    var fileByteArray = [];
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(myFile);
    reader.onloadend = (e) => {                     
        var buffer = <ArrayBuffer>reader.result;
        var uintArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        var binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uintArray);

        let resourceModel = new Model({
            contentType: myFile.type,                            
            fileName: myFile.name,
            fileContent: binaryString
         });                   

    } 
}
```

C# Code:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.fileContent))
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(model.FileContent);
    File.WriteAllBytes(RESOURCES_SAVE_PATH, bytes);                
}
```

It all looks like it works, there are no errors thrown during execution. However, when you go to open the file, the file wont open as it doesnt recognise the contents.

Any ideas how i can get this working?

Comment: "it doesn't recognise the contents" — *what* doesn't recognize the contents? Can you verify that the file has the right size, or look at it with a hex dump program?

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for your reply. I am just testing this with a basic img at the minute. The transferred img has a larger size than that of the original img, so something is definitely not correct. Original was 20kb and transferred img is 25kb

Comment: Ah well here's a thing: JavaScript strings are 16-bit characters.  In an image file, there could be pairs of bytes that look like Unicode 16-bit code points. (There can also be invalid code points.)

Comment: Hmm,  I don't think  Encoding.UTF8 is the right tool to read the contents.

Comment: https://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx/

Comment: I did something similar recently and I ended up using a base64 string to transfer the data.

Comment: @JeremyBenks Thanks, i just switched to this approach and its now working perfectly. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Are you trying to upload a file via ASP NET? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JeremyBenks for the idea of using a Base64 string instead. The relevant changes for my example are as follows:

JS

```
var binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uintArray);
```

For this

```
var b64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,uintArray));
```

C#

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(model.FileContent);
```

For this

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(model.FileContent);
```

Comment: Just remember: There is quite some overhead generated when using base64. That is a disadvantage.

Comment: @JeremyBenks Thanks, yeah i have added a reduce function to try and help with this